# How can i create an automatic redirect to AppStore or PlayStore based on Device?

Tags: html, wordpress, server, hosting, admin

For example: xyz.com/app-download
This domain (and only THIS!) shoudl redirect Android users in the PlayStore and iOS users in the AppStore.

If this domain is opened by Windows or Linux it should not redirect, but show the content, which is on the site!

This should preferrably be done by .htaccess file editing.

Can anyone come up with a nice and understandable solution for this?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

with a little Javascript you can achieve this, just add this code to the page

```js
<script>
function redirectByMobileOS() {
  var userAgent = navigator.userAgent || navigator.vendor || window.opera;

//for Android
    if (/android/i.test(userAgent)) {
        window.location.href = "http://www.link-for-android.com";
    }

//For iPhone / iPad / iPod  (iOS
    if (/iPad|iPhone|iPod/.test(userAgent) && !window.MSStream) {
        window.location.href = "http://www.link-for-iphone.com";
    }
}
</script>
```

and call the function on page load from your `<body>` tag like this

```
<body onload="redirectByMobileOS()">

</body>
```